# ViewModelFactory and ViewModel with no constructor args

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel

I got MyViewModel, which constructor is empty

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<RxBleClient> rxBleClient = new MutableLiveData<RxBleClient>();


    public MyViewModel() {

    }
    
    public MutableLiveData<RxBleClient> getRxBleClient() {
        return rxBleClient;
    }

    public void setRxBleClient(MutableLiveData<RxBleClient> rxBleClient) {
        this.rxBleClient = rxBleClient;
    }
}
```

and I want to provide new model like this, but there is issue:

```
MyViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

error: no suitable constructor found for ViewModelProvider(MainActivity)
        MyViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
                            ^
    constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner,Factory) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStore,Factory) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

I did implements ViewModelProvider.Factory

```
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    ViewModelFactory() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        try {
//            what do I need to do here?
            return modelClass.newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but I do not know what to do, to return factory which have no args.
How to achieve that?

 Thanks

Comment: Where are you creating your `MyViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be missing the dependency needed for this to work. Make sure you have the `appcompat` dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

Alternatively some Google libraries actually come with `appcompat` already as a dependency. For example:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

Comment: MainActivity does inherit from AppCompactActivity, also I did migrate to AndroidX like this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX.
Also ViewModelProvider is from androidx: import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
Is there a way to create a factory with no args? Or some hacks to deal with this problem?

Comment: That's very odd, I am not having any issue with your code when testing it.

Comment: Does your project have an `appcompat` dependency? Removing that in my project recreated the error you described

Comment: I have not appcompact dependency. Could you write down your version of ViewModel implementation in gradle.build?

Comment: Nothing changed.
The answer is to add those lines:
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

//     ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"